# Dropdowns are in disable state in csc picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, csc

When added boxdecorations the state and place dropdowns are in disable state. In [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/csc_picker#:%7E:text=A%20flutter%20package%20to%20display%20a%20country%2C%20states%2C%20and%20cities,city%20all%20around%20the%20world.)
in flutter but when using default decoration everything works fine